# Not able to display DateTime from json on page with PHP

Tags: php, json, date, datetime, strtotime

I have some JSON data that I have pulled from an api which looks like the following:

```
{
  data: {
    loans: {
      totalCount: 301,
      values: [
        {
        name: "Anastacia",
        status: "fundRaising",
        plannedExpirationDate: "2017-08-19T22:10:06Z"
        },
        {
        name: "Mercy",
        status: "fundRaising",
        plannedExpirationDate: "2017-08-19T22:10:05Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to display the names and totalCount on the page, but not the plannedExpirationDate.

```
$json_a = json_decode($curl_response, true);

//This works:
echo $json_a['data']['loans']['values'][0]['name'];

//this does not:
echo $json_a['data']['loans']['values'][0]['plannedExpirationDate'];

//this does not either. It prints a date in 1970.
$date= $json_a['data']['loans']['values'][2]['plannedExpirationDate'];
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class is a great replacement that will help you achieve what you wish.

eg.

```
$d = new DateTime($date);
echo $d->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there is there are only two values, so the index #2 is undefined. If you change your code to this it will work:

```
   $date= $json_a['data']['loans']['values'][1]['plannedExpirationDate'];
```

The 1970 date is a big clue - that means the you're parsing something false-y.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the OP said that `echo $json_a['data']['loans']['values'][0]['plannedExpirationDate'];` didn't work either. I'm going to try putting a test case together.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the date's format in your json file you have Y-m-d, you should change the format to be compatible with your PHP code, or create your own format in PHP suiting your needs check the official documentation : 
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using incorrect index.
This can be seen clearly in the var dump shown below for the parsed JSON (note the index that you want is 1 and not 2):

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["loans"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["totalCount"]=>
      int(301)
      ["values"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(3) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(9) "Anastacia"
          ["status"]=>
          string(11) "fundRaising"
          ["plannedExpirationDate"]=>
          string(20) "2017-08-19T22:10:06Z"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(3) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(5) "Mercy"
          ["status"]=>
          string(11) "fundRaising"
          ["plannedExpirationDate"]=>
          string(20) "2017-08-19T22:10:05Z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A better way to do this along with the proper index ([running example](http://ideone.com/c6Cmen)):

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "data": {
        "loans": {
            "totalCount": 301,
            "values": [{
                    "name": "Anastacia",
                    "status": "fundRaising",
                    "plannedExpirationDate": "2017-08-19T22:10:06Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mercy",
                    "status": "fundRaising",
                    "plannedExpirationDate": "2017-08-19T22:10:05Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}';


// to see the index more clerly we can use this
//var_dump(json_decode($json, true)); 


// to check for any parsing errors
switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
}

echo "\n";

$json_a = json_decode($json, true);

//This works:
echo $json_a['data']['loans']['values'][0]['name'];
echo "\n";

//this does not:
echo $json_a['data']['loans']['values'][0]['plannedExpirationDate'];
echo "\n";

//this does not either. It prints a date in 1970.
$date= $json_a['data']['loans']['values'][1]['plannedExpirationDate'];
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($date));

?>
```

You can also use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class available in php to format the parsed value for `plannedExpirationDate`.